# Reorganizing a PDF's pages by check number

Tags: pdf, adobe, adobe-reader

Here's the situation.  My workplace has a box of checks, years worth for a client.  I want to know if it is possible to scan these in, convert to text, and then have adobe reorder the pages based on the check number.  The pages are all uniform and the check number is in the same place every time.  I was thinking maybe there's a way trick adobe by telling it the check number is actually the page number and then maybe it could do it from there?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this works: 1. scan to images 2. obtain check numbers from images using OCR tool 3. presort images based on check numbers. 4. final PDF conversion.

Comment: It can be done, using Acrobat. Assuming that a whole stack of checks turns into a single PDF, run OCR, retrieve the check number page by page, write it into an array, sort that array, get the ordered list of page numbers, extract and reassemble the individual pages in that order in a new, sorted, document.

Comment: I suppose you should look into MICR capable OCR tool as checks in most cases using MICR font.